# Getting "ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE" as Validation Code in Hyperledger Explorer for every transaction / block

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-explorer

I Have two Orgs in My Network. I have Created a channel deployed the chaincode on both Orgs (Org1 and Org2) and received code as VALID.

Chaincode approved by both Orgs, Checked committed readiness and Committed the chaincode. log goes like...

`2021-10-04 14:30:52.864 IST [chaincodeCmd] ClientWait -> INFO 001 txid [eff4729bb0fcb0ac21b6b4c4ee78de75d9fc3bc04b67fdd1cc22c9b67044d93a] committed with status (VALID) at localhost:9051`

`2021-10-04 14:30:52.911 IST [chaincodeCmd] ClientWait -> INFO 002 txid [eff4729bb0fcb0ac21b6b4c4ee78de75d9fc3bc04b67fdd1cc22c9b67044d93a] committed with status (VALID) at localhost:7051`

`=============== Commit chaincode definition Org 1 ============================== Committed chaincode definition for chaincode 'sample' on channel 'samplechannel': Version: 1, Sequence: 1, Endorsement Plugin: escc, Validation Plugin: vscc, Approvals: [Org1MSP: true, Org2MSP: true]`

``` =============== query commited from Org 1====================`` Committed chaincode definition for chaincode 'sample' on channel 'samplechannel': Version: 1, Sequence: 1, Endorsement Plugin: escc, Validation Plugin: vscc, Approvals: [Org1MSP: true, Org2MSP: true] ```

I have gone through similiar issues posted and added
`BlockValidation: Type: ImplicitMeta Rule: "ANY Writers"` in my `configtx.yaml`

Transaction gets executed without any error. able to view transaction hash.
But getting `ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE` in explorer.

I have added sceenshots below.

Can any one please help what is wrong / needs to be changed here ?

Thanks in advance.
Image for reference -

[ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlc6S.png)
[Chaincode deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwrfT.png)

Answer (score 0):

The default endorsement policy is MAJORITY. It means your transaction to be validated by a majority of channel members.

To change the endorsement policy, you can specify `Channel/Application/Endorsement` in `configtx.yaml` to `ANY Endorsement`. Fabric will use this config as the default endorsement policy in all chaincode.

Or you can specify the policy for each chaincode by define it when approve & commit chaincode. For example:

```
peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg --channelID mychannel --signature-policy "OR('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')" --name mycc --version 1.0 --package-id mycc_1:3a8c52d70c36313cfebbaf09d8616e7a6318ababa01c7cbe40603c373bcfe173 --sequence 1 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --waitForEvent

peer lifecycle chaincode commit -o orderer.example.com:7050 --channelID mychannel --signature-policy "OR('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')" --name mycc --version 1.0 --sequence 1 --init-required --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --waitForEvent --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
```

See more in [Hyperledger Fabric documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/endorsement-policies.html#setting-chaincode-level-endorsement-policies)

Comment: I have followed the same, and still getting the same issue in hyper ledger explorer.